# Windows keyboard shortcut for missing fn buttons?

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey, hotkeys

My `f6` and `f12` buttons are missing, and I would like to create shortcuts for them (e.g `ctrl+6` etc.)
Is this possible?
I tried looking into `AutoHotKey`, but couldn't find how to define the output as an `fn` button.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my bug, Adding a reference with the `ahk` script that works with `ctrl+n`

```
^1::
send {F1}
return
^2::
send {F2}
return
^3::
send {F3}
return
^4::
send {F4}
return
^5::
send {F5}
return
^6::
send {F6}
return
^7::
send {F7}
return
^8::
send {F8}
return
^9::
send {F9}
return
^0::
send {F10}
return
^!1::
send {F11}
return
^!2::
send {F12}
return
```